# Issue with lazy evaluated object binding in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following binding

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: tubeRack.containers">
    <li data-bind="drop: { handler: $parent.dropHandler.bind(null, $index()) }">
    ...
```

And the problem is that the `dropHandler.bind` apparently only gets evaluated when used in the binding, which makes `$index()` always return the index of the *last* element.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a way to make `dropHandler` bind to *each* index of the elements in the list?

The `drop` binding is defined as follows

```
ko.bindingHandlers.drop = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
        var self = this;

        var options = valueAccessor();
        self.accept = options.accept || _.constant(true);
        self.handler = options.handler;

        $(element).droppable({
            tolerance: 'pointer',
            accept: function (draggable) {
                return self.accept(dragData);
            },
            drop: function(evt, ui) {
                self.handler(dragData);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you supply the source of the `drop` binding? (since I believe this isn't part of vanilla knockout.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `index()` belongs to the foreach, as you've identified correctly, it will only ever have the correct value during the evaluation of that foreach. Thus, I suggest the following workaround to force a timely evaulation. I couldn't test it, unfortunately, but it should at least be able to serve as a hint:

```
<li data-bind="drop: { handler: (function(idx) { $parent.dropHandler.bind(null, idx); })($index()) }">
```

Comment: This was in fact not the problem, knockout handles the evaluation of `$index` just fine, but the binding was defined in a problematic way (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that the binding kept a silly reference to `this` and setting the handler function on it, resulting in the `handler` variable being overridden.